# Question about SEO and Domains

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)
>   [Move subdomain into subdirectory SEO question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10548/move-subdomain-into-subdirectory-seo-question)

This is my first post on here as I am mainly on Stackoverflow and Serverfault.  I have been programming for at least 10 years now, have made hundreds of websites but I have just recently started getting into Design and the SEO side of sites, sad that I have been overlooking these for so many years.

I have pretty good knowledge from all my years of SEO but I have never really looked into it until now.

My question, I would like to build a site that targets many different key words for the search engines, for an example.  Let's say I built a site about Outdoor activities called `outdoorreview.com` and I planned on having many sections
 `hunting` `fishing` `Hiking` `camping` `cycling` `climbing` `etc...`

For best Search Engine results, how could I get the most search engine traffic to all these ares?

Also how should I structure the way to get to them, `outdoorreview.com/Hiking/` or `hiking.outdoorreview.com` ?

Comment: "I have just recently started getting into Design and the SEO side of sites" / "I have pretty good knowledge from all my years of SEO" ..?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10548/move-subdomain-into-subdirectory-seo-question answers your second question (short answer - it doesn't make any difference).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your main category pages 'nexus' pages that users who're interested in that particular topic will go to, bookmark and link to. Magazine style WordPress themes are great for this but you can use almost any news site as an example.
2. It doesn't really matter for SEO although I've found that people will build unsolicited links to your site better when you use folders than subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Dots, hyphens, slashes etc are simply noise in a url. It matters not.

Provided the content is of sufficient (and by sufficient, I of course mean *outstanding*) quality, you will rank accordingly, regardless of url.